# Получить в php массив с изображениями(количеством, именами, не важно) в папке, и передать его в js для обработки

Tags: javascript, php, массивы

Практически ничего не понимаю в php, больше по js, но обещаю подтянуть как только решу задание!) есть несколько папок, в них неизвестное количество изображений, нужно получить либо список имен (массив) файлов в папке(IMAGES), либо их количество и передать для дальнейшего перебора в циклах в js и вывода на экран.

Нужен по сути код, который я смог бы вставить, и в консоли увидеть количество файлов через js

Получить файлы через php
Добавить в массив
Передать массив в js

Прошу пояснить на пальцах, второй день уже мучаюсь с этим...

Comment: $dir = 'C:/test/test';
$files1 = myscandir($dir);

Answer (score 1):

Предположим у вас структура фалов такая: несколько папок с изображениями и в них соответственно лежат картинки

```
images_1/
     car_photo.jpg
     man_picture.jpg
     screenshot.png
images_2/
     foobar.jpg
     barfoo.jpg
```

Используйте функцию [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php) для сканирования директории по регулярному выражению:

```
<?php

/* получаем массив изображений в папках */
$files_array = glob("images_*/*.*");

/* кодирует массив в JSON формат */
$json = json_encode($files_array);

/* выводим JSON */
echo $json;
```

Результат в $files_array будет примерно таким

```
Array                             
(                                 
    [0] => images_1/car_photo.jpg     
    [1] => images_1/man_picture.jpg     
    [2] => images_1/screenshot.png   
    [3] => images_2/foobar.jpg   
    [4] => images_2/barfoo.jpg 
)
```

Ну и JSON формат выведется

```
[
"images_1\/car_photo.jpg",
"images_1\/man_picture.jpg",
"images_1\/screenshot.png",
"images_2\/barfoo.jpg",
"images_2\/foobar.jpg"
]
```